# Placard with 3 red crosses - probably WW1

Tags: world-war-one

I found a placard in my great-grandfather's scrapbook, it's with some other WW1 items so I'm guessing it's related to the war.  But what is it?

[image]

Comment: What are the length and width?

Answer (score 6):

This is a Red Cross Service Flag.

[image: Have YOU a Red Cross Service Flag? by Jesse Wilcox Smith]
<sup>*Image source: [Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/94514686/)*</sup>

Each smaller cross indicates an additional Red Cross member in the house beyond the first. You can read more on the American Red Cross Society during WW1 [here](https://wwionline.org/articles/american-red-cross/).

Comment: Excellent!  What did it mean to be a "Red Cross member"?  Just that you had donated money, or time, or both?

Comment: @BettyCrokker For most members - yes, that meant they made some kind of donations. I've added a link to an article on American Red Cross' activities during WW1, if you're interested in reading more about them.